# How to Know if there are many requests to servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I'm wondering if i could know if there are many request to the same servlet in order to display an "many request " massage or something like that, but what i know is that the servlet initiate only one instance, and each request processed by on thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a javax.servlet.ServletRequest**Listener** to be notified whenever an HTTP request is initialized.

A request listener is a good candidate for tracking requests, because the **web** **container** notifies the listener of new requests by calling its **requestInitialized**( ) method

Add a counter variable into "MyListener" and increment it inside requestInitialized() method to get the no.of requests.

[image]

Comment: By this way can i know the number of request ?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can accept this answer, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a `counter` variable and increment it in `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods.